# Symfony2 kernel exception event not handling fatal error exception in production mode

Tags: symfony, exception, symfony-2.5

I make a listener for exception handling. Below is my code

**`services.yml`**

```
kernel.listener.prod_exception_listener:
    class: MyBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**`ExceptionListener.php`**

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // no fatal exception goes here others are coming in this function
        // like 403,404,500 are coming in this block

    }
}
```

What additional work I need to do for fatal exceptions in production mode? Because in dev mode fatal errors are coming in listener.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it the following way,
in my services.yml

```
api_exception_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ApiExceptionSubscriber
    arguments: ['%kernel.debug%', '@api.response_factory', '@logger']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
api.response_factory:
    class: AppBundle\Api\ResponseFactory
```

my response factory look like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ResponseFactory
{
    public function createResponse(ApiProblem $apiProblem)
    {
        $data = $apiProblem->toArray();

        $response = new JsonResponse(
            $data,
            $apiProblem->getStatusCode()
        );
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and the Api subscriper class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Api\ApiProblem;
use AppBundle\Api\ApiProblemException;
use AppBundle\Api\ResponseFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ApiExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $debug;

    private $responseFactory;

    private $logger;

    public function __construct($debug, ResponseFactory $responseFactory, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->debug = $debug;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // only reply to /api URLs
        if (strpos($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo(), '/api') !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        $e = $event->getException();

        $statusCode = $e instanceof HttpExceptionInterface ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;

        // allow 500 errors to be thrown
        if ($this->debug && $statusCode >= 500) {
            return;
        }

        $this->logException($e);

        if ($e instanceof ApiProblemException) {
            $apiProblem = $e->getApiProblem();
        } else {


            $apiProblem = new ApiProblem(
                $statusCode
            );

            /*
             * If it's an HttpException message (e.g. for 404, 403),
             * we'll say as a rule that the exception message is safe
             * for the client. Otherwise, it could be some sensitive
             * low-level exception, which should *not* be exposed
             */
            if ($e instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
                $apiProblem->set('detail', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse($apiProblem);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Adapted from the core Symfony exception handling in ExceptionListener
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception
     */
    private function logException(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $message = sprintf('Uncaught PHP Exception %s: "%s" at %s line %s', get_class($exception), $exception->getMessage(), $exception->getFile(), $exception->getLine());
        $isCritical = !$exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface || $exception->getStatusCode() >= 500;
        $context = array('exception' => $exception);
        if ($isCritical) {
            $this->logger->critical($message, $context);
        } else {
            $this->logger->error($message, $context);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2020: as of Symfony 5 this is no longer necessary**

I have handled this by overriding Kernel::handle to call the ExceptionListener manually

```
public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true): Response
{
    try {
        return parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new \Exception("There was an issue booting the framework");
    } catch (\Throwable $throwable) {
        $exception = new FatalThrowableError($throwable);

        $event = new ExceptionEvent($this, $request, $type, $exception);
        /** @var ExceptionListener $exceptionListener */
        $exceptionListener = $this->container->get(ExceptionListener::class);
        $exceptionListener->onKernelException($event);

        return $event->getResponse();
    }
}
```